# Why sudo openvpn cannot work here?

Tags: debian, sudo, root, openvpn

I can use openvpn as root as `openvpn ...` but not with `sudo openvpn ...` although `masi` is in `sudo` group. 
I think I should be able to do it. 
I think it can be safer to do so with `sudo`. 
The following is the work process starting with `sudo` approach, then root approach and lastly about details of the openvpn files in Nordvpn

```
masi@masi:~$ sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/ro2.nordvpn.com.udp1194.ovpn 
[sudo] password for masi: 
Options error: --auth-user-pass fails with 'nordvpn.txt': No such file or directory
Options error: Please correct these errors.
Use --help for more information.

masi@masi:~$ su
Password: 

root@masi:/home/masi# cd /etc/openvpn/

root@masi:/etc/openvpn# openvpn ro2.nordvpn.com.udp1194.ovpn 
Sun Mar  5 21:45:20 2017 OpenVPN 2.3.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Nov 12 2015
Sun Mar  5 21:45:20 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016, LZO 2.08
Sun Mar  5 21:45:20 2017 WARNING: --ping should normally be used with --ping-restart or --ping-exit
Sun Mar  5 21:45:20 2017 Control Channel Authentication: tls-auth using INLINE static key file
Sun Mar  5 21:45:20 2017 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Sun Mar  5 21:45:20 2017 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Sun Mar  5 21:45:20 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->131072] S=[212992->131072]
Sun Mar  5 21:45:20 2017 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Sun Mar  5 21:45:20 2017 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]93.115.241.34:1194
^CSun Mar  5 21:45:37 2017 event_wait : Interrupted system call (code=4)
Sun Mar  5 21:45:37 2017 SIGINT[hard,] received, process exiting
```

Permissions of openvpn files in Nordvpn

```
root@masi:/etc/openvpn# ls -la * | grep ro3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3003 Sep  2  2016 ro3.nordvpn.com.tcp443.ovpn
```

I do

```
$ sudo grep nordvpn.txt /etc/openvpn/ro2.nordvpn.com.udp1194.ovpn 
[sudo] password for masi: 
auth-user-pass nordvpn.txt
```

OS: Debian 8.7

Comment: I'm not an expert, but the 'No such file' error may indicate that the envirnoment of 'sudo' and 'su' are different.

Comment: This 'nordvpn.txt' is located somewhere?

Comment: I think that you should modify ro2.nordvpn.com.udp1194.ovpn adding a full-path: auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/nordvpn.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are running as root, you are running in in `/etc/openvpn` directory, and as such it finds the `nordvpn.txt` file there.

When you are running it with `sudo` you are running it from other directory, and as such it does not find the file, as you the configuration file is not referencing it with full path.

I would advise changing the configuration file `/etc/openvpn/ro2.nordvpn.com.udp1194.ovpn`;

where you find the line:

```
auth-user-pass nordvpn.txt
```

change it for:

```
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/nordvpn.txt
```

You should then be able to use it from `sudo`

Comment: I have many such files. I think this works `sed -i 's|auth-user-pass nordvpn.txt|auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/nordvpn.txt|g' *.ovpn`. Confirmed, it works at least with a few files of mine.